# put icon and text in same line, opposite ends

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I know similar questions have been asked before but I couldn't fix this myself. I have an icon and a text that should be displayed on both ends of the screen. The icon should be at the left end while the text should be at the right end.

However, the Text extends the screen and is hidden from the right side, even if I add marginRight or paddingRight. How can I fix this?

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaViewContainer}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.topTextContainer}>
          <BackArrow containerStyles={styles.arrowContainer} arrowStyles={styles.arrow}></BackArrow>
          <Text style={styles.allFavoritePlaces}>Alle Lieblingsorts</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  arrowContainer: {
    marginTop: 0,
    marginBottom: 0,
    marginLeft: 0,
  },
  arrow: {
    color: 'black',
    paddingTop: 0,
  },
  allFavoritePlaces: {
    alignItems: 'flex-end',
    paddingRight: moderateScale(0),
    paddingBottom: moderateScale(10),
  },
  topTextContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginVertical: moderateScale(15),
    height: moderateScale(30),
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
  },
});
```

Here's a **codesandbox** too: https://snack.expo.io/@nhammad/sponaneous-candy

[image]

Comment: Does adding a `max-width` of  `100vw` to the parent help?

Comment: Also your code sandbox doesn't work.

Comment: Nope, not in react native style sheets at least. I updated the link and added an image @Simplicius

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opend it in the dev tools. The container of your arrow has some `width` assigned to it, when the screen gets to small it pushes the text out of the viewport.

[image]